# Handlebars each sentence not looping

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have this template

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Nombre del foro</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        {{#each data}}
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{ id }}</th>
            <td>{{name}}</td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}

    </tbody>
</table>
```

with this input data

```
[
{"id":1,"name":"Foro general"},
{"id":2,"name":"Otro foro"},
{"id":14,"name":"Nuevo foro"},
{"id":15,"name":"Nuevo foro"},
{"id":16,"name":"Nuevo foro"},
{"id":17,"name":"Nuevo foro"},
{"id":18,"name":"Nuevo foro"}
]
```

and the output is this

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Nombre del foro</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I don't know why the JSON is treated as an empty array of objects.
Any ideas what am I missing?

## Edit 2: Remove confusing code that was unnecessary

```
forumListTemplate(data){
    var forumListTemplate = 
    `
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Nombre del foro</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {{#each data}}
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{ id }}</th>
                <td>{{name}}</td>
            </tr>

            {{/each}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    `
    var forumListCompiled = compile(forumListTemplate);
    var forumListHTML = forumListCompiled(data);
    return forumListHTML;
}
```

I have checked that result returns the input data mentioned above

Comment: Can you include the relevant `javascript` to where you append the data?

Comment: Updated :) @NewToJS. I also used to test it and it's the same result http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/

Comment: I am not familiar with `servicio_API.getForums()` is this some other third party/plugin you are using? Also I don't see any element with the id of `divForumsList` So the `javascript` you have added is useless if not confusing to me.

Comment: I'm sorry I misread what you were asking for, I've updated the question again. I think this is what you wanted me to post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing an object with the field `data` to the compiled template.

```
var forumListCompiled = compile(forumListTemplate);
var forumListHTML = forumListCompiled({data: data});
return forumListHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth to you or anyone else viewing this question (maybe nothing, if you're committed to using Handlebars) you don't need a third-party library to accomplish this in modern JavaScript.  You can just use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

I understand that your original question was about how to use Handlebars, but maybe this will be useful to you now or down the road.  The advantage is, no need to import an outside library and increase the size of your application:

```js
const inputData = [
  {"id": 1, "name": "Foro general"},
  {"id": 2, "name": "Otro foro"},
  {"id": 14, "name": "Nuevo foro"},
  {"id": 15, "name": "Nuevo foro"},
  {"id": 16, "name": "Nuevo foro"},
  {"id": 17, "name": "Nuevo foro"},
  {"id": 18, "name": "Nuevo foro"}
]

function forumListTemplate(data){
    const trs = data.map(entry => (
            `<tr>
              <th scope="row">${entry.id}</th>
              <td>${entry.name}</td>
             </tr>`
             )
    )
    
    return `<table class="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">#</th>
                  <th scope="col">Nombre del foro</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                ${trs}
              </tbody>
            </table>`
}

console.log(forumListTemplate(inputData));
```